# Error "none of the index are in the columns"

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to make a script in pandas to correct an excel file. At some points, in "column12", cell is left blank and it moves all data one cell to the right. Vencli is my database. To fix it my idea was to create a variable that spots and index where the cell breaks and then, it replaces it with the data from the cell of the next column, 13. Here's my code:

```
cond1 = vencli[vencli['Column12']] == ''
cond2 = vencli[vencli['Column12']] == str(np.nan)

vencli.loc[vencli[cond1 or cond2].index.tolist(), ['Column12']] = vencli[cond1 & cond2]['Column13']
```

However, I got this error message:

```
KeyError: "None of [Index([ '39.72',  '79.44',  '79.44',  '39.72',  '37.63',  '79.44', '238.30',\n        '79.44',  '75.26',  '79.44',\n       ...\n         '9.69',  '39.96',  '35.96',  '29.07',   '8.99',  '29.97', '162.12',\n         '8.99',  '26.97',  '17.50'],\n      dtype='object', length=1048575)] are in the [columns]"
```

Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably several things. Best would be to provide a reproducible example. `or` should be replaced by `|`

Comment: I tried that too. Is correct, but the error persist.